# jQuery: Style all empty child TDs only if the first (:first) TD contains no text (:empty)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

[image]

I need some jquery code to style all empty child tds only if the first td contains no text.

Right now my code styles all empty TDs as a greyish color (see image).

I only want the first row to be styled because the first TD contains text.  In other words, I need to test if the first TD contains text and if so, add the grayish color on that row, if it is blank then don't add the coloring to the empty TDs.

**jsbin for the above code:**

http://jsbin.com/ojemuf/1/edit

Comment: The first and third sentences are contradictory. Can you edit the post to clarify.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope I'm understanding your question right
loop trough the tr elements and if the first is not empty add a color to the empty td's inside the tr element

```
$('tr').each(function () {
  if(!$(this).find('td').first().is(':empty'))
    $(this).find('td:empty').css('background', '#ccc');
});
```

--- edit ---
Reversed edition of Mathletics

```
$('tr td:first-child').not(':empty').siblings("td[class*='_crew']:empty").css("background", "#DDCEC0");
```

Comment: Maybe the second option is cleaner, based on the answer of Mathletics

Comment: I'm sure there is a weird edge case somewhere, but in general, never use `each` for selection. (I tossed you an upvote anyway.)

Answer (score 6):

Select rows, check if first child **not** is empty, get its matching siblings:

<s>$('tr td:first-child:empty').siblings("td[class*='_crew']:empty").css("background", "#DDCEC0");</s>

```
$('tr td:first-child:not(:empty)').siblings("td[class*='_crew']:empty").css("background", "#DDCEC0");
```

Apparently I had it backwards!

Comment: Nice! Can it be reversed?  I want the color add if there is text in the first TD.

Comment: `$('tr td:first-child:not(:empty)')` or `$('tr td:first-child').not(':empty')`; I forget if psuedo-selectors play nice when nested.

Comment: This only gets direct siblings in the same row. Is that the intent or should it colorize the whole table? @rick-ootes

Comment: @B2K did you test it? It colors the whole table. `$('tr td:first-child').not(':empty')` selects the first non-empty `td` in __all__ rows.

Comment: @Mathletics - I added a control table to my fiddle, rather shocked at the results. I've updated my answer below accordingly. Thanks for pointing out my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

The question is a bit unclear whether you want to update the entire table when the first element is not empty or if you want to update every matching row. For the entire table, you can try this:

```
$("td:first:not(:empty)")
     .closest("table")
         .find("td[class*='_crew']:empty")
            .css("background", "#DDCEC0");
```

From the description, it seems the other answers missed the fact that he wants this applied when the first element is NOT empty.